# What is the alternative to a <ros2arduino.h>

Tags: ros2, arduino

I am using Arduino Mega.

I wanted to configure it to create a ros2 topic using the ros2arduino header.

However, I found out that the header cannot be used because it can only be supported from 32bit or higher

In this case, what idea can you recommend?

Currently, the board is connected to I2C communication, and it seems that the main board will also be connected to Arduino through I2C communication.
(Currently, I am connecting from Ubuntu installed on my PC for testing purposes.)

Thank you so much for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have to use I2C, why don't you try Serial?
Here seems to be an example of an interface that can communicate serially with Ros2.

https://github.com/AnrdyShmrdy/ros2_serial_interface

Comment: Thank you for answer. I decided to use serial instead of i2c. And we would like to repeat this once again and pass it on through spi.

Comment: So, if this is an area you are interested in, I would like to inquire first. Instead of Arduino, I decided to use Raspberry Pi pico. I want to use it as a controller like a simple Arduino. In this case, is it possible to communicate with Pico through SPI from the main Linux program(PI4)? (Pico wants to receive images through SPI communication, process them, and send them out through SPI.) (In addition, Pico wants to operate radar and motors through I2C communication)